# WP 8.1 app connection to SharePoint

Tags: rest, sharepoint, windows-phone-8.1

I'm developing an app for windows phone 8.1  .
I want to read and write data to and from Microsoft SharePoint.
I'm using REST API and my problem is **I have no idea how to get the access token needed in order to gain access to SharePoint**.
This is what I have so far:

```
                HttpWebRequest spRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(jsonRequest);
                spRequest.Method = "GET";
                spRequest.Accept = "application/json; odata=verbose";
                //spRequest.Headers["Authorization"] = "Bearer" + accessToken;            
                HttpWebResponse endpointResponse = (HttpWebResponse)await spRequest.GetResponseAsync();
                Stream dataStream = null;
                StreamReader reader = null;
                string responseFromServer = null;
                dataStream = endpointResponse.GetResponseStream();
                reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
                responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

Maybe my approach is all wrong. I'll appreciate any insights, please help I spent a week on google trying to figure out how to it.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get an OAuth2 access token you have to direct the user to a dedicated web page where he enters his credentials, if successful, you will receive the token in a response from that page.

In Windows Phone, you may find it easier to implement by using the [WebAuthenticationBroker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.security.authentication.web.webauthenticationbroker.aspx) class.

In your case, are you connecting to SharePoint Online, or to SharePoint 2013?

Comment: I haven't seen anything about a dedicated web page in sharepoint. How can I implement such a thing?

Comment: For Sharepoint Online, I have used this login address: https://login.windows.net/common/oauth2/authorize?client_id={MYCLIENTID}&response_type=code&scope=MyFiles.Read&prompt=login&redirect_uri={MYAPPREDIRECTURI}

Check this documentation for more information about getting access tokens: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/files-rest-operations#UsetheOffice365clientlibraryGetanaccesstoken

Comment: {MYCLIENTID} is the client id generated when I registered the app on my sharepoint?

Comment: yes. same for the redirect uri - I think it does not have to be an actually existing page, just some valid url

Comment: A new problem, sharepoint should ask the user if he trusts my app. On a regular browser the question shows and there are 2 buttons "trust" "don't trust". the problem is that int the WebAuthenticationBroker It's not showing! I'am so frustrated! Does anyone has a solution?